# Blocking invoice creating in background (using programs YV60SBAT - SDBILLDL)

Tags: abap

While creating an invoice through  YV60SBAT-SDBILLDL via job - we have to do some checks.
If some of these custom checks don't pass, we should restrict the system not to create an invoice for that particular document and should continue for the rest of the documents. Also, that error message should be displayed in batch job log..

Here is an example:

Delivery documents: say 1,2,3

1-Invoice should generate

2-Invoice should not get generate because some check doesn't pass

3-Invoice should generate...

I've tried with Enhancement spot `ES_SAPLV60A` Point `fakturaposi_auftragspositio_02` and set `us_rc = 4` and `RETURN` (include `LV60AA29`), as found on some forum .. but the system doesn't access this code.

Comment: YV60SBAT is a custom program, but there is the official program RV60SBAT.

Comment: This information doesn't help :)

Comment: I need the place where I can IMPORT FROM MEMORY some IDs previously EXPORTed where my checks are performed ..  in order to interrupt the invoice creation and pass to the next one.

Comment: A comment is not meant to help the Original Poster, but to post any information that doesn't correspond to an answer. For instance, you could edit your question to indicate RV60SBAT because people don't know your custom program. Don't forget that one of the key principles of Stack Overflow (SO) is to provide Reproducible examples, in your case YV60SBAT does not comply to the "reproducible" principle. Please have a [tour for more information about SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check the help center too.